# Google Drive UI API "Open with" not working with Google docs?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs

I would like for a user to be able to right click on Google Doc in their Drive, select "Open with" and click my app.

Following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk), error occurs on step 10.

I've created the app, authorization, etc. In "Drive UI Integration" settings panel, I have to fill out the following fields:

[image]

In Default MIME Types, I've tried adding `document`, `google-apps.document`, `application/vnd.google-apps.document`. None of those work - it's either rejected when saving or does not seem to have any effect - i.e. "Open with" menu on Google Docs does not list my app. Other MIME types, such as pdf, image, folder work fine.

What is the problem here?

A bit more about the use case:
My app allows user to select a Google Doc from their Google Drive which then gets automatically shared with other team members (i.e. the app adds permissions to it). The flow goes like this: user authorizes the app to open files on their drive, then select the Google Doc through file picker. This returns fileId to the app which can then add necessary permissions to it.

Comment: Have you considered to create a G Suite addon maybe? Also you could try to make this integrated with Apps Script, like there is a custom menu that will share your doc. 
If you want to follow with the UI implementation maybe try to give more detail on what is happening right now, what step are you, error message, etc

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation on how to integrate [Open with](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open):

> App-specific files are defined in the Default Mime Types and Default File Extensions fields when you configured a Drive integration. G Suite files are defined in the Secondary Mime Types and Secondary File Extensions fields when you configured a Drive integration.

Basically in your case you may want to edit a document but first you will need to convert it to your desired format (`text/html`, `text/plain`, `application/pdf`, etc).

> For MIME types defined in the Secondary Mime Types field, the Drive UI displays a dialog asking the user what file type to convert the G Suite file to. For example, if you select a Google Doc in the Drive UI and Secondary Mime Types field suggests your app supports text/html, text/plain, or application/pdf, the Drive UI asks the user if they want to convert to HTML, Plain text, or PDF.

In [this section](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/integrate-open#specific) there is an explanation on how you need to use the [`files.export`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export).

Also it may be useful the following [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats) with all the possible formats for every type of document.

**TL;DR:** For G Suite documents the mimeType goes in the `Secondary` field

Comment: Thanks, the use case is not to convert a Google Doc into other format, just getting its fileId. Tried putting mimeType for Google Docs in the Secondary field to no effect - app doesn't show up in "Open with". Maybe I'm not using the right mimeType? In the documentation it says `application/vnd.google-apps.document` but that causes an error.

Comment: If you just want to get the file id why don't you just use the API itself? I'm confused about your end goal here, maybe try to expand a bit on that in your question

Comment: Sure, added some context to the original question!